# System.OverflowException in converting js to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

```
var pin = parseInt(form.mac.value.slice(-6), 16) % 10000000;
```

I'm convert the `JS` to `C#` like this

```
var pin = Convert.ToInt16(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Substring(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Length - 6)) % 10000000;
```

and then I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: Value was either too large or too
>   small for an Int16.

Comment: What is the value of `Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Substring(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Length - 6))` exactly?

Comment: the value is 6 digits numer from mac address14:cc:20:30:76:50 -> 307650

Answer (score 1):

The value is too big for `Int16`. Try to use `Convert.ToInt32`.

```
var pin = Convert.ToInt32(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Substring(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Length - 6)) % 10000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `Convert.ToInt16`. The value is too big to fit in `Int16`.

The `Int16` value type represents signed integers with values ranging from negative `32768` through positive `32767`. `307650` is way bigger than `32767` so you should use a bigger type to store the value in. `Int16` uses 2 bytes of memory to store integral value, `Int32` will use 4 bytes and can manage to store a bigger range of integers. `Int32` is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with values that range from negative 2,147,483,648 through positive 2,147,483,647.

Try this one

```
var pin = Convert.ToInt32(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Substring(Networks[NetworkIndex, 0].Length - 6)) % 10000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `int.TryParse("your number", out int)` This will not throw any exception(When you'll get null in string.). If it is parsed then it means the value is correct or you can explicitly throw exception from your code.

Take a look.

[Int.TryParse](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse)